# How to run GUI application in Docker?

Tags: arch-linux, docker, manjaro, gui

I am trying to install Packet Tracer in my Parrot OS docker container following [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjfuKye4I7rAhVX73MBHfNZBg4QFjAIegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2F%40SaravSun%2Frunning-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110&usg=AOvVaw0WkrfrkjT7bGO5eQ1H8QKL) tutorial, and my *Dockerfile* looks like this for now (just to test):

```
FROM parrotsec/core
COPY PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb /root/PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y /root/PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb
```

and when I run the command

```bsh
docker build -t gparrot .
```

I get the following error:

```bsh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  181.1MB
Step 1/3 : FROM parrotsec/core
 ---> 167d5a59b3ce
Step 2/3 : COPY PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb /root/PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1df7860c2821
Step 3/3 : RUN apt-get install -y /root/PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb
 ---> Running in 2bbb80e41fd9

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 packettracer : Depends: sudo but it is not installable
                Depends: dialog but it is not installable
                Depends: xdg-utils but it is not installable
                Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache but it is not installable
                Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installable
                Depends: libpulse0 but it is not installable
                Depends: libnss3 but it is not installable
                Depends: libxss1 but it is not installable
                Depends: libasound2 but it is not installable
                Depends: libxslt1.1 but it is not installable
                Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y /root/PacketTracer_731_amd64.deb' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Kindly tell me what's the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The `parrotsec/core` baseimage doesn't provide a X displayserver. Just stick to the guide use ubuntu - install those dependencies with `apt-get`. Add an entrypoint and expose needed ports in your Dockerfile